# python can't see packages after update Mac OS X to 10.9.2

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Before update my mac configured once python. I don't know how configuration has been created. After update, python interpreter can't see old package. I am discover 3 directories: 
Firstly **/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/** http://yadi.sk/d/GbD6sS7LMZ78Z
Secondary **/Library/Frameworks/** http://yadi.sk/d/5DMN-bd3MZBnT
and maybe my old pycharm projects: **/Users/myuser/Python/** http://yadi.sk/d/nvo67PLnMZDeV

Python path variable:

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 

[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)

['',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_watermark-0.0.1-py2.7.egg',

 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',

 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.4-py2.7.egg',

 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',

 '/Users/myuser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

>>>
```

System path:

```
 echo $PATH
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
    /Users/dns/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:
    /opt/local/bin:
    /opt/local/sbin:
    /usr/bin:
    /bin:
    /usr/sbin:
    /sbin:
    /usr/local/bin
```

pip freeze get this result:

http://yadi.sk/d/JBj9U7vOMZEci

but if I try import this modules I see next:

http://yadi.sk/d/xu8U18-5MZFpD
some package is exists, but other that exits in pip freeze is not exits in import (for example twisted and pillow). What the F? Where is problem? in PIP? What need do, why resole this problem? Need edit path variables or anything other?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling it with pip?

Comment: I am execute:
`pip freeze > pip_freeze.txt`
`sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install -r pip_freeze.txt --upgrade`
all package return "Requirement already up-to-date"